# Total Order between sets.

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory

If I have two streams x1 and x2 and I define a prefix ordering on them such that,

x1 <| x2 :⇔  x1=x2 V ∃β ∈ streams that x1.β = x2.

Are they in Partial Order as well as in total order?

Comment: It's hard to understand your notation and what does 'streams' mean?

Comment: That means, x1 and x2 are some streams where x1 is a prefix of x2. For example, if x1 = a,b,c and x2 = a,b,c,d,e,f then x1 is contained in x2 as some sort of prefix.

The statement says, if x1 is a prefix of x2 then either they both are equal or there exists a beta which when concatenated with x1 makes it equal to x2.
Would this relation of prefix ordering be in total order?

Comment: It is a partial order, it is not a total order. TO see it isn't a total order it's enough to consider two strings $x_1$ and $x_2$ which differ in the first bit, for instance $x_1=01$ and $x_2=10$, then clearly there is no $\beta$ with the given property.

Comment: Git Gud:could you please explain that when you consider x1 = 01 and x2 = 10 then of course they 'Do Not' satisfy the axiom for total order, but then they would not even satisfy partial order. Or would they?
I am actually pretty confused how do you differ total order from Partial order (PO) one? What I know is, for the PO the three axioms of Reflexivity, Transitivity and Anti-symmetry should be true. But, is it that for all elements of the set they should be true or for some?

Comment: If it is for some elements or for all, is something that you much check on each condition. In fact, reflexivity, antisimmetry and transitivity are all universal conditions, so they must be satisfied for all elements of the set. There is an answer below, if there is something you don't understand, feel free to ping me again.

Answer (score 1):

To see that it's not a total order, take the counter-example provided by user Git Gud in the comments, i.e. take $x_1=01$ and $x_2=10$. Then there is no $\beta$, such that $x_1.\beta = x_2$.

To prove that it is a partial order, you have to check reflexivity, antisymmetry and transitivity. You get reflexivity for free from the defnition.

To check antisymmetry, assume there are $x_1$, $x_2$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$ such that
$$ x_1.\alpha = x_2 \wedge x_2.\beta = x_1\text{.}$$
This yields
$$ x_1 = x_1.\alpha.\beta$$
and thus $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be empty streams. Hence $x_1=x_2$.

To check transitivity, let $x_1.\alpha = x_2$, and $x_2.\beta=x_3$. Thus $x_1.\alpha.\beta = x_1.(\alpha.\beta) = x_3$. So $x_1\le x_3$